# puppeteer : launch with no-sandbox and no-headless

Tags: puppeteer

I must launch puppeteer with this line:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']} )
```

But for debugging, I need launch **headless: false**

I tested:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']} 
headless: false});
```

But it doesn't work.

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

replace with following code

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: false,
     args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
  })
```